# Drawbacks of Find-S

Tags: machine-learning, computer-science

One of the commonly cited drawbacks of the Find-S algorithm is that the hypothesis h returned by Find-S may not be the only h that fits the data.

Now, I have a problem understanding this, as surely there can only ever be one "most-specific" hypothesis?

For example:
Given the following training data:

[image]

We would get the following iterations i:

i0: S = {Japan, Honda, Blue, 1980, Economy} (using example 1)

i1: S = {Japan, Honda, Blue, ?, Economy} (using example 3: skipping example 2 since it's negative)

i2: S = {Japan, Honda, ?, ?, Economy} (using example 5: skipping example 4 since it's negative)

i3: S = {Japan, ?, ?, ?, Economy} (using example 6)
End (skipping example 7 since it's negative)

So, the way I see it, there can't be any other most specific hypothesis for this data set other than  S = {Japan, ?, ?, ?, Economy}. But obviously I must be wrong somehow.
Could somebody explain to be how my assumption is incorrect? Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

I'm learning this myself. But as far as I can see it, I came up with the same answer as you. However in your `i1` step you missed the `Toyota` which would have gained you a ? earlier on like below:

```
S1 = {Japan, Honda, Blue, 1980, Economy}

S2 = {Japan, ?, Blue, ?, Economy}

S3 = {Japan, ?, ?, ?, Economy}

S4 = {Japan, ?, ?, ?, Economy}
```

I've literally just started reading about this half an hour ago, but as far as I know so far, Find-S will only give you one hypothesis because you're going from a `specific ==> generalised` form.

If however you were going from a `generalised ==> specific` form, then you'll end up with potentially many examples. I am here because that's why I'm trying to find out how that works.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, the answer is correct. The final hypothesis is { Japan, ?, ?, ?, Economy }

For a better understanding, I include the algorithm steps over here -

1. Start with the most specific hypothesis.
   h = {ϕ, ϕ, ϕ, ϕ, ϕ, ϕ}
2. Take the next example and if it is negative, then no changes occur to the hypothesis.
3. If the example is positive and we find that our initial hypothesis is too specific then we update our current hypothesis to a general condition.
4. Keep repeating the above steps till all the training examples are complete.
5. After we have completed all the training examples we will have the final hypothesis when can use to classify the new examples.

You can learn more from here -[Find-S-Algorithm](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/ml-find-s-algorithm/)